# Displaying a message to user when first item added to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, notice

In Woocommerce, is there a way to display a message to a customer when they add the first item to the basket?

I want to warn customers that they have 30 minutes to shop before their cart is emptied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so simple as you have:

- NORMAL "Add to cart" buttons (Not AJAX)
- AJAX enabled "Add to cart" buttons (If it's enabled in Woocommerce settings)

So below you will find 2 hooked functions for both (where you will set your message):

```
// For NORMAL add to cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_message_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
function custom_message_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
       $message = __("1st cart item message here", "woocommerce");
       wc_add_notice( $message, 'notice' );
    }
    return $passed;
}

// For AJAX add to cart (if enabled)
add_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_before_product_cat_loop', 'custom_print_message', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'custom_print_message', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'custom_print_message', 11 );
function custom_print_message() {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        $message = __("1st cart item message here", "woocommerce");

        // HERE BELOW, replace clothing' with your product category (can be an ID, a slug or a name)
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-info hidden" style="display:none;">' . $message . '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('body').on('added_to_cart', function(){
            $('.woocommerce-info.hidden').show('fast');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and Works.